# Iterate over an object with delay

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, delay, delayed-execution

I am trying to iterate over nested children of an object, but need have a delay after every child. Normally I would just write a recursive function and use that to iterate over an object, but this happens near instantly. How can I do this with a delay?

I thought about saving the index in a variable and accessing children using that, then increasing the index every time a `setInterval` is run, but how can this be expanded to take nesting into account?

Function to iterate:

```
function iter(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i].command);
        if (typeof obj[i].contains == "object") {
            iter(obj[i].contains);
        }
    }
}
iter(object);
```

Example object:

```
[
    {
        "command":"do (5)",
        "contains":[
            {
                "command":"move.up()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"move.left()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"if (kind == \"item\")",
                "contains":[
                    {
                        "command":"move.down()",
                        "contains":false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "command":"move.right()",
                "contains":false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: change `iter(obj[i].contains);` to `setTimeout(iter.bind(this, obj[i].contains), 100 * i);`

Comment: Since you understand well how to deal with a setInterval, go for a two-step solution 1) build the wanted output inside a flat and simple array 2) display this array with a setInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a flat array from the hierarchy:

```
function iter(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    result.push(obj[i]);
    if (typeof obj[i].contains == "object") {
      result = result.concat(iter(obj[i].contains));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var items = iter(object);
```

Now you can iterate the array with a timer and an index:

```
var index = 0;
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
  if (index < items.length) {
    console.log(items[index].command);
    index++;
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Demo:

```js
var object = [
    {
        "command":"do (5)",
        "contains":[
            {
                "command":"move.up()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"move.left()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"if (kind == \"item\")",
                "contains":[
                    {
                        "command":"move.down()",
                        "contains":false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "command":"move.right()",
                "contains":false
            }
        ]
    }
];

    function iter(obj) {
      var result = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        result.push(obj[i]);
        if (typeof obj[i].contains == "object") {
          result = result.concat(iter(obj[i].contains));
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    var items = iter(object);

    var index = 0;
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      if (index < items.length) {
        log(items[index].command);
        index++;
      } else {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);

function log(str) {
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += str + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```